# filter con texto contenido

Tags: jquery

Uso esta sentencia para realizar un filtrado en una variable object JSON:

```
var a = $(Data2).contains(function (index, value) { 
    return value.ApPaterno === Apellido; 
});
```

Funciona correctamente pero siempre y cuando el texto sea exactamente igual, hay una forma de evaluar algo parecido al Like de SQL???

Comment: Que has buscado/investigado e intentado? Por qué no te funcionó? Mira [ask] para mejorar la calidad de tu pregunta. Un saludo

Comment: Muchas gracias, pues la verdad he intentado con métodos como .match o .contains pero me da como resultado que no se reconocen las funciones.

Answer (score 1):

El metodo `.indexOf()` que retorna la posicion de la primera palabra que sea igual al argumento:

```js
var indice = "hola mundo, como estas".indexOf("com");
console.log(indice > 0 ? "contiene la letra com" : "no contiene la letra com");

var indice2 = "hola mundo, como estas".indexOf("bue");
console.log(indice2 > 0 ? "contiene la letra bue" : "no contiene la letra bue");
```

Entonces en tu caso seria:

```
var a = $(Data2).contains(function (index, value) { 
    return value.ApPaterno.toLowerCase().indexOf(Apellido.toLowerCase()) > 0;
});
```

Si lo que quieres es filtrar el con jquery utiliza la funcion [`grep()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.grep/) que filtra el array que cumplan con la condicion especificada:

```js
var data = [
  {ApPaterno: "Martines", nombre: "Carlos"},
  {ApPaterno: "Martones", nombre: "Mateo"},
  {ApPaterno: "Maruecos", nombre: "Handel"}
];
var apellido = "nes";
var coleccionFiltrada = $.grep(data,function(persona, index){ 
  
   return persona.ApPaterno.indexOf(apellido) > 0;
});

console.log(coleccionFiltrada)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Y si quieres hacerlo sin jquery, entonces utiliza la funcion filter del array:

```js
 var data = [
      {ApPaterno: "Martines", nombre: "Carlos"},
      {ApPaterno: "Martones", nombre: "Mateo"},
      {ApPaterno: "Maruecos", nombre: "Handel"}
    ];
    var apellido = "nes";
    
 var datosFiltrados = data.filter(function(persona, index){ 
    return persona.ApPaterno.indexOf(apellido) > 0; 
 });
 
 console.log(datosFiltrados);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! pero me devolvería la(s) posición(es) donde se encuentre? o me devolvería la palabra? es que esa variable es como una tabla, entonces necesito que me devuelva todas las filas que contengan esa palabra en el campo ApPaterno

Comment: Retorna la posicion de la palabra. El metodo contains filtra el array en base a una condicion por lo que deberia de filtrarte el array.

Comment: @lois6b si, retorna boolean. ¿Porque?. Actualize mi pregunta, por error puse un corchete de mas.

Comment: Si, nada. lo decia porque a Erik le comentaste que "retorna la posicion de la palabra" pero tu hablas de el `index` yo del `return` ^^'

Comment: Gracias por su ayuda chicos, pero no me reconoce la función .contains :( hay alguna forma de ocupar el filter??? es que supongo que debería modificar nadamás el  

    return value.ApPaterno === Apellido; 

pero no sé con qué debería reemplazar el ===

Comment: Mira la respuesta actualiza y dinos si te funciono.

Answer (score 0):

Podrías intentar con esto:

```
var a = $(Data2).contains(function (index, value) { 
    return (value.ApPaterno.toLowerCase().indexOf(Apellido) >= 0)
});
```

`indexOf()` retorna -1 si no encuentra el `string`.

Comment: se te han adelantado. Intenta añadir o mejorar la respuesta para que sea diferente a la ya publicada

Comment: Daniel, en tu perfil pone que se va a eliminar tu usuario en 8h.. lo hiciste tu?

Comment: Si pero lo cancelé, fue sin querer, no se si se ha cancelado

Comment: lo cancele yo para poder hablar contigo. A punto estuviste de perderlo hahha y llevabas buena trayectoria. Me alegro que sigas, un saludo